# Using PHP to grab an RSS feed url?

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, metadata, echo

I'm trying to load an rss feed url from a form in a wordpress meta box. I know the code I have in the $rss->load field is wrong right now. I'm wondering how to properly retrieve the url. As a note,

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "atp_blogurl", true); ?>
```

is used in the regular html at the bottom, so I know it's the right php call in that instance.

Here's what I have right now:

```
<div id="rss_img">
<?php
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "atp_blogurl", true); ?>');
$feed = array(); 
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array ( 
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        );
    array_push($feed, $item);
}
$limit = 4;
for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
            $description = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", " ", $description);
    echo '<strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'" target="_blank">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
    echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small><br />';
    echo '"'.$description.'<br/><br />';
}
?>
<br>
<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "atp_blogurl", true); ?>"    target="_blank">View All</a>
</div>
```

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the double php tags inside here:

```
$rss->load(get_post_meta($post->ID, "atp_blogurl", true));
```

Comment: Excellent, don't forget to accept answers!